# Sharing data between controllers from a $rootScope $watch function

Tags: angularjs, watch, rootscope

I currently have a `$watch` that checks for changes in screensize and sets a variable accordingly.

```
$rootScope.$watch('windowView', function(view) {
    if (view === 'small') {
        self.device = 'mobile';
    }
});
```

I do this logic within a parent controller, but I want to have access to this variable in child controllers. Accessing a parent variable within a child works fine:

```
$scope.controller.device
```

however the child does not update when the watch has updated only the parent scope.

I want to be able to access the watched value dynamically without duplicating `$rootScope.$watch` in each child controller is this possible?

I've tried to create a service that includes the the `$rootScope.$watch` and then call that in each of my controllers however i get back the same value of onload as opposed to on watch.

Comment: Use an object not a primitive for the variable...then you will have object inheritance throughout the app and internal watches will update views

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo on jsfiddle.
The demo contain parent ctrll and child ctrll which share device property via controller as of the parent.
On the controller I listen to resize event and update the device property to
'mobile' in case $window.innerWidth < 800 else device will be 'desktop'

[DEMO jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/901ek9vv/3/)

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('parentCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
var self = this;

var w = angular.element($window);
w.on('resize', function(event) {
  if ($window.innerWidth < 800) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      self.device = 'mobile';
    });
  } else {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      self.device = 'desktop';
    });
  }
});}).controller('childCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

Comment: this seems to have the same issue, it changes to mobile but then never updates again